# Using mongodump with a standard Mongo URI

Tags: mongodb, database-backups

The `mongo` client can connect with a standard URI:

```
mongo mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@<server>:<port>/<db>
```

However, `mongodump` seems to require an awkward syntax breaking this up into different arguments:

```
mongodump -u dbuser -p dbpassword -h server -p port -d db ...
```

Is there a quick and easy way to pass a URI to `mongodump` as well?

Comment: Yes. `--uri` can be used since MongoDB 3.4.6. See [TOOLS-1567](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1567?jql=text%20~%20%22mongodump%20URI%22)

Comment: @NeilLunn happy to accept your comment if you post it as an answer.

Comment: Okay. Didn't even notice it and probably just sent the link "on the fly" in between doing something else.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `--uri` option was added within a minor release of MongoDB 3.4.6. This was referenced in the JIRA issue [TOOLS-1587](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1567?jql=text%20~%20%22mongodump%20URI%22).

It actually did not get official documentation until the MongoDB 3.6 release, but it's [now in the manual page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-uri)

> --uri 
>   *New in version 3.4.6.*
>
> Specify a resolvable URI connection string for the mongod to which to connect.
>
> The following is the standard URI connection scheme:
>
> ```
> mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
> ```
>
> For detailed explanations of the components of this string, refer to the [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) documentation.

The same `--uri` option is added to other tools such as [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/), [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) and [`mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/).

Comment: if you have a `mongodb+srv://` connection string, remove the `+srv` and it should work

Comment: mongoclient 4.2 - no need to remove the srv. just works.

Answer (score 18):

**Answer: 05-15-2020**

I know this is a late answer, but it solved my problem.
To dump using an `URI`, do:

```
mongodump --uri=[uri]/[db]
```

where:

- uri is your URI (e.g. **mongodb+srv://john:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@cluster0-jdtjt.mongodb.net**)
- db is the database that you want to dump (e.g. **sales**)

So in this artificial example, it would be like this:

```
mongodump --uri=mongodb+srv://john:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@cluster0-jdtjt.mongodb.net/sales
```

So if this really did not work, edit the file `/etc/resolv.conf` and change `nameserver` value to e.g. `8.8.8.8`, like this:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

# nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
options edns0
```

Now it should works.

Answer (score 16):

**Easy steps to getting dump and restore whole database at once with any data loses**

**take dump in the local machine**

```
mongodump --uri "mongodb+srv://username:password@dbexmplae-fsddf.igt.mongodb.net/dbname" --out "C:\databaseDump"
```

**locate to the dumped folder and restore to local database **

```
mongorestore --db dbname C:\databaseDump\dbname
```

**restore to remote database**

```
mongorestore --uri "mongodb+srv://username:password@dbexmplae-fsddf.igt.mongodb.net/dbname" --db dbname C:\databaseDump\dbname
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and easy string to understand

`mongodump --uri='mongodb://...url/...db-name' --out $(pwd)`

or

`mongodump --uri='mongodb+srv://...url/...db-name' --out $(pwd)`

Depending on your implementation, will dump the whole database of $(db-name) located at $(url) and place the contents into your current working directory $(pwd)

Answer (score 0):

As the answer is already posted but if RBAC is enabled then use the following syntax.

> mongodump --uri **url/databaseName** --port **mongoport** -u
> **username** --authenticationDatabase **admin**

--**authenticationDatabase** should point to admin as user details and credentials will be stored in admin database by mongodb

provided a tested and working example below on v7.0.5

> ```
> mongodump --uri "mongodb://127.0.0.1/SK_Mongo_Application" --port 27001 -u root --authenticationDatabase admin
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Even if you supply the `uri` option, you still need to supply the `db` option. The documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/ is incorrect when it says that the `db` option is "incompatible" with the `uri` option. If you don't supply the `db` option together with the `uri` option you get a `don't know what to do with file` error for each .bson file that you're trying to restore. I tested using mongorestore version 3.6.9 on ubuntu and from mac osx.

Comment: Actually, it's the opposite. The documentation explicitly states that when you use --uri some parameters must be ignored, including --db https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/

Comment: You have to concatenate /your_db in the uri string